# Removing duplicate urls python BeautifulSoup using set() blows apart the urls

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, duplicates

In python I have used BeautifulSoup to scrape urls from a website for a project and everything works great until I try to remove the duplicates by passing the tags into a set  object. The tags are "blown apart". Here is my code and example of print results.

````
file = open('parsed_data.csv', 'w')

for link in soup.find_all('a', attrs={'href': re.compile("^http")}):

    soup_link = str(link)
    if soup_link.endswith('/') or soup_link.endswith('#'):
        soup_link = soup_link[-1]

    soup_link_unique = str(set(soup_link))

    print (soup_link)
    print (soup_link_unique)

    file.write(soup_link_unique)
    file.flush()
    file.close
```
Before passing into set object:
<a href="https://www.census.gov/en.html" onfocus="CensusSearchTypeahead.onSearchFocusBlur(false);" tabindex="2">
<img alt="United States Census Bureau" class="uscb-nav-image" src="https://www.census.gov/etc/designs/census/images/USCENSUS_IDENTITY_SOLO_White_2in_TM.svg" title="U.S. Census Bureau"/>
</a>

After passing into a set object:
{'I', 'S', '\n', 'C', '>', 'u', '"', '-', 'i', 'Y', 'L', 'M', 'p', '.', 'c', ')', 'B', '2', 't', 'N', '<', ' ', 'b', 'w', 'e', 'E', '/', 'O', ':', 'U', 'x', 'o', 'W', 'f', '(', 'l', 'D', 'F', 'g', 'd', '_', '=', 'n', 's', 'h', 'a', 'T', 'v', 'r', ';', 'm', 'y'}
````

Comment: The variable soup_link is a string, you do `soup_link = soup_link[-1]` which with it being a string only gets the final character of the string. Hence why when you do you set command, it is only comparing against one letter each time and will always be unique. At least, just from looking at the code that is.

Answer (score 1):

Create a set before the `for` loop and add new elements to the set using the method `add()`:

```
soup_link_unique = set()

for link in soup.find_all('a', attrs={'href': re.compile("^http")}):    
    soup_link = str(link)
    if soup_link.endswith('/') or soup_link.endswith('#'):
        soup_link = soup_link[-1]   
    soup_link_unique.add(soup_link)
```

#### Example:

```
my_set = set('ABCDE')
print(my_set)
# {'E', 'D', 'C', 'B', 'A'}
```

#### vs

```
my_set = set()
my_set.add('ABCDE')
print(my_set)
# {'ABCDE'}
```

Comment: Thank you I'll try this.